# Why ListView can not click and ImageDialog not appear?

Tags: java, android, image, android-listview, onclicklistener

Please help me , I want to make the action when I hit the ListView will display ImageDialog , but when I am running the application , an error like the following :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bongkorr/com.hospifinder.A1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This my .java file:

### informasi.java

```
public class Informasi extends Activity {
protected static final ItemDetails ItemDetails = null;
protected Object Object;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.informasi);

    ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 

            Intent i = null; 
            if (position == 0){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A1.class);
                } 
            else if(position == 1){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A1A.class); 
                }
            else if(position == 2){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A2.class);
                }       
            else if(position == 3){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A3.class);
                }       
            else if(position == 4){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A4.class);
                }
            else if(position == 5){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A5.class);
                }

            else if(position == 6){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A6.class);
                }

            else if(position == 7){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A7.class);
                }

            else if(position == 8){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A7A.class);
                }

            else if(position == 9){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A8.class);
                }

            else if(position == 10){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A9.class);
                }

            else if(position == 11){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A10.class);
                }
            else if(position == 12){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A11.class);
                }
            else if(position == 13){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A12.class);
                }

            else if(i !=null)
            startActivity(i);     
        }
    });
}

   private ArrayList<ItemDetails> GetSearchResults(){
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

    ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS SARI ASIH KARAWACI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Imam Bonjol No.38 (Pos Polisi) Kota Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(1); //1a
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS SARI ASIH CILEDUG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. HOS. Cokroaminoto No.38 (Depan Mall Ramayana) Ciledung Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(2); //1
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSU KAB TANGERANG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Jend. Ahmad Yani No. 9 Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(3); //2
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS USADA INSANI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. KH. Hasyim Ashari No. 24 Cipondoh-Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(4); //3
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS AN-NISA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Gatot Subroto No. 96 Cibodas sari Km 3 Cibodas, Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(5); //4
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS DINDA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Galuh No.2, Jatiuwung, Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(6); //5
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS BHAKTI ASIH");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Raden Saleh No.10 Karang Tengah Ciledug, Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(7); //6
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS ISLAM SARI ASIH AR-RAHMAH");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jalan Ks Tubun No. 44Kwang Jaya, Karawaci, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(8); //7
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSK SITANALA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Dr Sitanala, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(9); //7a
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSU HERMINA TANGERANG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. KS Tubun No.10 Pasar Baru, Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(10); //8
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS. ARIYA MEDIKA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Industri Raya I Blok A. No. 1-11, Jatake - Kodya Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(11); //9
    results.add(item_details); 

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS MELATI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Merdeka No.92, Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(12); //10
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS AWAL BROSS");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. MH. Thamrin No.3 Kebon Nanas, Cikokol, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(13); //11
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSUD Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Pulau Putri Raya, Kel. Kelapa Indah Kec. Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(14); //12
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT SELARAS");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Raya Lapan Rumpin, Suradita, Cisauk Suradita, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(15); //13
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA SELARAS");
    item_details.setItemDescription("JL. Raya Serang, Km 185, Bojong, Cikupa, Talaga, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(16); //14
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("CIPUTRA HOSPITAL");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Mekar Bakti, Panongan,Tangerang, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(17); //15
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS MITRA HUSADA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Kp. Melayu Barat, No. 11A, Teluk Naga, Kec. Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(18); //16
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT MULIA INSANI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jalan Raya Serang KM 16,8, Cikupa, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(19); //17
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS PARAMITA TANGERANG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("JL Raya Serang, Km. 28, 5 Kavling FL No. 8, Balaraja, Kawasan Industri CCM");
    item_details.setImageNumber(20); //18
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT QADR");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Komplek Islamic Village, Karawaci, Kec. Tangerang, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(21); //19
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("SILOAM HOSPITALS LIPPO VILLAGE");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Siloam No. 6, Lippo Karawaci 1600, Kec. Tangerang, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(22); //20
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSUD BALARAJA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Rumah Sakit No. 88, Desa Tobat, Balaraja, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(23);//21
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("EKA HOSPITAL CENTRAL BUSINESS DISTRICT (CBD)");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Lot IX BSD City Serpong");
    item_details.setImageNumber(24);//22
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT OMNI INTERNATIONAL");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Alam Sutera Boulevard Pondok Jagung, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(25);//23
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT INTERNATIONAL BINTARO");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. MH. Thamrin Blok B3 No. 1 Sektor 7 Bintaro Jaya");
    item_details.setImageNumber(26);//24
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA ICHSAN MEDICAL CENTER");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Jombang Raya No 56 Bintaro Sektor IX");
    item_details.setImageNumber(27);//25
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT MEDIKA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("BSD City, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(28);//26
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT ISLAM ASSHOBIRIN");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Raya Serpong KM.11 Pondok Jagung");
    item_details.setImageNumber(29);//27
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA BUAH HATI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Aria Putra Ciputat");
    item_details.setImageNumber(30);//28
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA BUAH HATI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Siliwangi Pamulang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(31);//29
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT BHINEKA BAKTI HUSADA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Cabe Raya No.17/34, Pamulang, Tangerang Selatan, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(32);//30
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT HERMINA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl.Kertamukti Ciputat Timur");
    item_details.setImageNumber(33);//31
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT SYARIF HIDAYATULLAH");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Ir. H. Juanda No.95 Kec. Ciputat, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(34);//32
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT SAKIT SARI ASIH CIPUTAT");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Otista Sasak Tinggi No. 3, Ciputat");
    item_details.setImageNumber(35);//33
    results.add(item_details);





return results;


}
}
```

### A1.java

```
public class A1 extends Activity {
private ListView   lv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.informasi);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_data);
arrayDialog.add("Dialog");
      lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayDialog));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(A1.this);

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(A1.this);


            //setting custom layout to dialog
            LayoutInflater inflater = A1.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            //adding text dynamically
            TextView txt = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            txt.setText("Put your dialogView text here.");
            ImageView image = (ImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));

            //adding button click event
            Button dismissButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
               dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

### custom_alert_dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/a1"
        android:src="@drawable/a1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Dismiss" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### informasi.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#0033CC"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


 <ListView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/listV_main"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Is there something wrong with my code ? whether because the ListView so influential and in case of error ?

Comment: In which line does it crashes? Does it crash in  startActivity(i);  ?

Comment: @JpCrow there is no error in the line , but when run applications, like **Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bongkorr/com.hospifinder.A1}: java.lang.NullPointerException**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `A1.java` You need to use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` because you are trying to set onClickListener to the listView and since listView is supposed to be attached to an adapterView it is throwing an exception. There is no Adaptor attached with to the listView.

Clicking on the listView is like clicking on an entireView which is not useful. Instead the click on the individual items of the listView should be handled.

try something like this:

```
suggestionsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
        //do your stuff to show the dialog
    }
    });
```

`OnItemClickListener()` should be of type`android.widget.AdaptorView.OnItemClickListener`

For alertDialog follow the code here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

EDIT

I tried this code for AlertDialog and it works for me

```
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(A1.this);

            // setting custom layout to dialog
            LayoutInflater inflater = A1.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            // adding text dynamically
            TextView txt = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            txt.setText("Put your dialogView text here.");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));

            // adding button click event
            Button dismissButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

`alertDialog` is a member variable in the class.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;
```

Comment: @JpCrow please see the edited answer. OP does the alertDialog works for you?

Comment: can you update the post with the new code that you are using for the AlertDialog?

Comment: I tried it myself and it works. I have updated the code. see if it makes a difference.

Comment: have error like `The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}`

Comment: sorry fixed it. I am showing the dialog from a fragment so that is why was using getActivity()

Comment: still not display, i have update my code, maybe this could give way